# firebase simple - data structure questions

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have been reading a little about how to structure your firebase database and i understand that you need to split your data into pieces so you don't forced the client to download all of the 'users' data.

So in this example you will get all the users data when you write

```
  ref.('users').once('value', function(snap)...

    /users/uid
    /users/uid/email
    /users/uid/messages
    /users/uid/widgets
```

but what if you specifically write the path to the location instead like

```
ref.('users/uid/email').once('value', function(snap)...
```

Will you still get all the users data or only the data in email ?

Comment: In your current structure it *is* possible to get the email for a specific user. But there is no way to get only the email for all users with this structure. Please make sure that the code in your question is syntactically correct, as it's hard to understand what you're looking for now.

Comment: The users is my key so if i reference that with ref.('users').once('value', function(snap)... i will also get all it children node but if i write ref.('users/uid/email').once('value', function(snap)... will i then only get the data from the email ?

Comment: With `ref.child('users/uid/email').once('value', function(snap)` it'll retrieve the email of the user with key `uid`. I recommend simply trying it, it's quite easy once you try a few listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, you set the ref to be the reference for your database (the whole database) and then you got methods to iterate through each piece of data of your database object, hence, a good practice is to set all your database as the ref and then work from there to go through what you want to go.

```
// will select the whole db
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

// will select the whole app object of your db
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('app');

// will select the whole users object of your db
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('app/users');
```

So, it is a good practice to set a variable like `firebaseRef` to be your whole firebase db and then iterate from there.

Now, if you write:

```
firebaseRef.child(`users/${uid}/email`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
  console.log('User email: ', snapshot.val());
}, e => {
  console.log('Unable to fetch value');
});
```

Yes, you will get what you're asking, but you need to use the `child` method to get to the objects of your firebase ref.

Comment: so if i reference users i get the whole database with all it child node like if i have users/uid/email, users/uid/message inside users right? but if i just make a path to just the users/uid/message with the reference ref("users/uid/message"), will i still get the whole database or just what that is inside the message ?